# Why in JS can you not set non-functions on prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypal-inheritance

I wasn't sure how to phrase the title but here's an example that just tripped me up big time

```
myLib.prototype._handlers = {};
myLib.prototype.destroy = function () {
  this._handlers = {};
}
```

I was writing tests when luckily it caught this issue. That destroy method doesn't actually work.

Why does this happen? I thought that properties on the prototype are created new for each `new myLib` instance, but from writing these tests *all* `new myLib` instances have these handlers.

Comment: Down vote because the number of prototype questions on here is mind blowing and the answers are usually very very good.

Comment: I couldn't find a dupe for this specific question tho @BenAston. Could you point me to the one you're saying has a good explanation?

Comment: Prototype properties are not created on `new`, a reference to the prototype object is.

Comment: Show an example where it does not work

Comment: @adeneo `var myLibInstance = new myLib(); myLibInstance.destroy();`

Comment: I find https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PMfcsYzj-9M extremely useful and clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set non-functions on the prototype.  The issue is that properties on the prototype are shared across all instances of the object.  That is usually NOT what you want for a data property, but it is what you want for a function property.

So, instead, you typically initialize data properties in the constructor for the object and that makes them "own" properties which are unique for each instance which is generally what you want.

---

> I thought that properties on the prototype are created new for each
>   new myLib instance, but from writing these tests all new myLib
>   instances have these handlers.

The prototype is an object that serves as a lookup mechanism for properties.  When you reference `var x = obj.prop`, Javascript first looks on the `obj` object itself to see if there is a property named `"prop"`.  If there is, that is considered an "own" property and it's value is fetched.  If not, then it goes to the prototype object to see if it has an "own" property named `"prop"`.  If it does, then it returns that value.  If it does not have that named property, then it checks to see if the prototype object has a prototype of its own and if so, it checks that one and so on...

So, the prototype serves as a lookup reference.  Nothing new is copied or created.  There's just a "reference" to the prototype that can be used for lookup.  This is why the prototype is shared among all instances.  It was designed this way on purpose for a number of reasons.  One reason is that it's storage efficient.  There is only one prototype object that all instances share so all those references don't have to be duplicated on every object instance.

When you assign to a property with:

```
obj.someProp = "foo";
```

it will only affect an "own" property.  It does not affect the prototype.  If there was an "own" property on the object named `"someProp"`, then it's value is updated.  If there was not, then a new "own" property is created on the actual object instance.  If there was a property of this name on the prototype, then that value is now essentially hidden because the Javascript property lookup scheme will find the "own" property first and will use that from then on (as long as it exists).

---

It may also be important to understand that when you assign a property in your `.destroy()` method such as:

```
myLib.prototype._handlers = {};
myLib.prototype.destroy = function () {
  this._handlers = {};
}
```

This does not actually touch the `myLib.prototype._handlers` value at all when you execute the `obj.destroy()` method.  Instead, `this._handlers = {};` makes a new property on the actual instance of the object, an "own" property.  Any reference to `this._handlers` will find the "own" property first and that's what will be used from then on so it may "seem" like it changed the prototype value, but the new "own" property is just masking the prototype value from then on.

Comment: Yes, perfect. That makes sense now. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> I thought that properties on the prototype are created new for each new myLib instance

No. Prototypes don't *create* anything. Prototypal inheritance is a cascading lookup system where lookups for a property on an object can escalate to prototype ancestors.

Each object has inherited properties and its "own" properties. Only "own" properties exist directly on an instance. Prototype values do not exist directly on the instance, but rather they are accessed when you ask for some property name on an object, and that property does not exist as an own-property.

Setting a property value always sets an own property directly on the object. So, `this._handlers = {}` sets (and possibly creates) the `_handlers` property directly on the instance you called the `destroy` method on. While property *access* does cascade up the prototype chain to find a property with the correct name, *setting* a property does *not* do so.

It's also critical to understand that the `this` value is set dynamically at function-invocation time, and may vary from call to call. That is, calling `instance1.destroy()` and `instance2.destroy()` will have different `this` values, even if the `destroy` function is the exact same function object. The only case in which `this` will be `myLib.prototype` is if you explicitly call `myLib.prototype.destroy()`.